# Replacement of OpenSSL by PolarSSL

Tags: c++, c, openssl, polarssl

I must change OpenSSL library to PolarSSL in my project, but i have some troubles. 
When i encrypt my session key with function below from from [OpenSSL library](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html)

```
RSA_public_encrypt((const int)session_key_len,(const unsigned char*) session_key
                  , (unsigned char*)encrypted_session_key, ctx->server_pubkey
                  , RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

The remote server will authorize me successfully. But if I use OpenSSL wrapper from [PolarSSL library](https://polarssl.org/api/openssl_8h.html), I receive different encrypted_session_key and remote server refused the connection.

RSA server public key size: 2048 bits.
Session key length: 64 bytes.
Encrypted key length: 256 bytes.

Whats wrong? Whats difference between function RSA_public_encrypt from OpenSSL and function rsa_pkcs1_encrypt from PolarSSL ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the example program *o_p_test* (I believe in *programs/test/*) in PolarSSL. It shows PolarSSL RSA encryption and OpenSSL encryption side by side..

I believe the OpenSSL wrapper is older and not maintained..